# How can I add a header to a PDF file using iText in C#?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I am trying to create a PDF using iText. I am trying to add a header that will appear on every page, but I want add some text like the report name that will be different for every page. How can I solve this problem? If you don't understand what I'm trying to ask, please see the example below:

#### In Page 1

```
Report Name: Test Report

Emp_id  Emp_Name  Emp_sal 

-----    -----      ------
-----    -----      ------
-----    -----      ------
```

#### In Page 2

```
Emp_id  Emp_Name  Emp_sal 

-----    -----      ------
-----    -----      ------
-----    -----      ------
```

**Note:** In Page 2, "Report Name" is not repeating.

Comment: Do you know how to create a new page? If you do, then just add the part you required at the beginning of the new page.

Answer (score 1):

In iText 5 you can create custom headers using page events.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace PDFLib.PageEvents
{ 
    public class CustomPageEvent : PdfPageEventHelper
    {
        private int _page;
        private readonly Rectangle _marges;
        private string _text;

        private static readonly Font FontHf = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE, 9);

        private readonly Dictionary<int, float> _posicions;

        public CustomPageEvent(string text){
            _text = text;
            _marges = new Rectangle(10, 10, _pageSize.Width - 20, _pageSize.Height - 20);
            _posicions = new Dictionary<int, float>
                         {
                             {Element.ALIGN_LEFT, _marges.Left + 10},
                             {Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, _marges.Right - 10},
                             {Element.ALIGN_CENTER, (_marges.Left + _marges.Right)/2}
                         };
        }

        public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            _page++;

            base.OnStartPage(writer, document);
        }

        public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            _page = 0;
        }

        public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            if (page==1)
                ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(writer.DirectContent, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(string.Format("{0}", _text), FontHf), _posicions[Element.ALIGN_CENTER], _marges.Top-10, 0);

            base.OnEndPage(writer,document);
        }

    }
}
```

Something like this. It can be simplified as I extracted this from a page event that did many more things as adding watermarks and custom headers and footers.

Comment: That should do quite nicely.  Bhaskara might need to play around with the page margins to reserve enough space for the header, but other than that you should be good to go.